# Is Zakir's map a plot mystery or a sign of a sloppy out-of-universe production?

Tags: another-life

In episode 9 of *Another Life* we see the planet Zakir, with three islands that are clearly copied from Earth: Mindanao (Philippines), Sulawesi (Indonesia), and New Guinea (Indonesia/Papua New Guinea.)

They're much bigger than they are on Earth (or Zakir is a much smaller planet), and New Guinea has been moved and flipped horizontally. Tricky!

What's going on here? Significant plot mystery? Concept art that got left in the final product?

[image: Screenshot of the planet Zakir from Another Life episode 9 another with a map of Southeast Asia]

Comment: That would be the show with dark matter that is literally black and obscures navigation, asteroid fields with rocks mere meters apart, boron-based viruses that can infect carbon-based organisms, scientists who remove their illuminated space suits on any planet with a vaguely reasonable oxygen concentration, and ships with exposed high-voltage electrical discharges? That would be the show where Washington D.C. is underwater and general AIs control FTL spaceships, while at the same time clothing, decor, and domestic appliances largely look indistinguishable from the modern day?

Comment: I am interested in the answer, but I think an answer of poor attention to detail is all but inevitable, as opposed to the more interesting "aliens did it."